# a custom view does not conform to protocol UICollectionViewDataSource

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I wrote a demo with swift 3.0 and wrapped a `UICollectionView` with a custom view. Lazy loading of collecionView and set the current view as the data source, but in the custom view extension to comply with `UICollectionViewDataSource` direct error. How to deal with it?

code:

**// cellID**

```
fileprivate let ContentCellID = "ContentCellID"

class PageContentView: UIView {

    // MARK:- lazy attributes
    fileprivate lazy var collecionView : UICollectionView = {
        // 1.create layout
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = self.bounds.size
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        // 2.create UICollectionView
        let collecionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collecionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collecionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collecionView.bounces = false
        collecionView.dataSource = self
        // register cell
        collecionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ContentCellID)
        return collecionView
    }()
    // MARK:- define attributes
    fileprivate var childVcs : [UIViewController]
    fileprivate var parentVc : UIViewController
    // MARK:- custom constructor
    init(frame: CGRect, childVcs : [UIViewController], parentVc : UIViewController) {
        self.childVcs = childVcs
        self.parentVc = parentVc
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**// MARK:- setup UI**

```
extension PageContentView {
    fileprivate func setupUI() {

        for childVc in childVcs {
            parentVc.addChildViewController(childVc)
        }

        addSubview(collecionView)
        collecionView.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

**// MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource**

```
extension PageContentView : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return childVcs.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collecionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ContentCellID, for: indexPath)

        let childVc = childVcs[indexPath.row]
        childVc.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
        cell.contentView.addSubview(childVc.view)
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to implement required method `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)`, implement it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return childVcs.count
}
```

**Note:** The method [`numberOfSections(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618023-numberofsections) that you have implemented is optional method if you doesn't implement than default section is `1`, so remove that method and return the `childVcs.count` in `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` that I have added above.

Answer (score 0):

Make your view comply to 'UICollectionViewDataSource' protocol by implementing all of the required functions in the said protocol which are:

```
// required functions
extension ThisView: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: `numberOfSections(in:)` is optional method not the require one, if you doesn't implement it than it will by default consider as your collectionView contains 1 section.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue even with the required methods listed above. The order of which they were listed solved my problem. So do the above and if you're still having issues, reorder the methods.